# Best practice: Where to place a mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

In a table for a users billing subscription info, there is the need for a field that states how often they are billed.  Currently the only options are monthly or annually.

What is best practice in this case?  Keep the actual value in a field of the subscription table or create a subscription frequency table, have annually be 1, and monthly be 2, and insert the ID into the subscriptions table?

Comment: IMHO, just put the value in the field.  No need for an extra lookup table, since the values in that wouldn't change.

Comment: I prefer to create the second table that holds the types of frequency, and then link it to the subscription table. It offers you a elegant way to translate the id by a human-readable name, and permits other frequencies to be added in future more easily.

Comment: But what if details pertaining to the value of that field change?  For example, what if we want to setup a monthly billing date, like the first of every month?  Then we realize that the 1st needs to really be the 7th?

Comment: If performance is a concern, I'd avoid the join, and just store the value. I'd use datatype `ENUM('','monthly','annually')`.  It's easy enough to add more values...  `ENUM('','monthly','annually','quarterly')`.  Works like a simple character string in the SQL, and takes a single byte of storage, no joins required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the specification, as given, with no other information...

My personal preference would be to just store the "subscription frequency" attribute in the entity table.

No need to create a separate table. (I don't see "subscription frequency" as being an entity in the system, and I've already got enough complexity with referential integrity and foreign keys for stuff I really need it for.)

I don't every query against my table to require a join to the "lookup" table to return a string value, out of an id. That just seems unnecessary.

Personally, I'd consider adding a column like this:

```
 subscription_frequency  ENUM('','monthly','annually')
```

If I need to add another value to the list:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
  MODIFY subscription_frequency  ENUM('','monthly','annually','quarterly')
```

The ENUM examples here require only a single byte of storage. And the INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT statements with the `ENUM` work as if it was a VARCHAR, with some funkiness with INSERT/UPDATE of string values that aren't in the enum list.

If there's reasons to avoid ENUM, then I would just store the VARCHAR.

---

If I needed the extra lookup table, I wouldn't use a surrogate id as the primary key. I would use the string value  'monthly', 'annually' as the primary key, and the foreign key column.  (I want to avoid requiring a JOIN to return a string from an `id`.)  If there's an order to the values in the list, I'd add a sequence column to order them.

Comment: *"I want to avoid requiring a JOIN to return a string from an id"* Why?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: Good question. An extra join makes SQL statements more complex. And a simpler statement is a benefit to the future reader, who we already tasking with tracking down joins to other entity tables... "subscription", "subscriber_account", "subscription_address", etc. And, if we store a surrogate `id` as a foreign key, then when we do an INSERT or UPDATE, we're going to require an extra SELECT to lookup of the `id` value. I weigh the benefits derived to the complexity cost, and evaluate that the additional complexity isn't cost effective.

Comment: Ahh, nice justification. Thanks!

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: The specification given is that we are storing a string value 'monthly' and 'annually'.  My personal preference is to not create a lookup table with a surrogate id column for every string value stored in a table. Of course, it could be done. We could create a lookup table for `first_name` attribute for subscriber, and store a surrogate `id` foreign key in our `subscriber` table. And require a join to that. We could do the same thing with subscriber `last_name`. That's workable. But again, IMO, the additional complexity isn't justified by any benefit we get.

Answer (score 1):

The billing-frequency is just an attribute of the subscription. And there is only one such attribute per subscription. So in my opinion there is no need for an extra table and join.

You could, of course, add an extra table with possible billing frequencies. Like `1: annually`, `2: monthly`, `3: weekly` or whatever. And using that `id` as value in the billing-frequency-field of your subscription table.

Alternatively, you could store the amount of billing processes per year in that field and make the "naming" in your application. (1 = annually, 12 = monthly, 52 = weekly and so on).

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to preference and expand-ability.  I would personally create another table called something like `SubscriptionFrequency` with attributes `id,description,billingFrequency,createDate,lastModifiedBy,etc...` or something to that effect. The value you store in your UserBillingSubscriptionInfo could be a foreign key to this new table's primary key.  If you do the other option (simply imply 1 = annual and 2 = monthly) I'd add descriptions to the schema or document somewhere how that relation works.

Comment: You mirror exactly what I was thinking.  While it isn't a very important decision, in case of scale-ability I think it's best to have a separate "SubscriptionFrequency" table.

Comment: I understand the notion not to over-complicate things. However, it may confuse other developers or stakeholders that access your database if those values aren't clearly defined. Additionally, adding new options becomes easy, and if you wanted to end up creating a user interface with SubscriptionFrequency options you could easily make a dynamic control with descriptions straight from the database instead of hard coding them in your application. Possibilities are endless, but in the end it's up to you or your development team.